# Why WHICH command doesn't give the expected path?

Tags: linux, shell

I have install an new **vim 7.3** in the system at ~/tools/bin
There is another **vim 7.2** in /usr/bin/vim.

I have add ~/tools/bin in the $PATH, and when I type vim in terminal it correctly launch the **vim 7.3**.
But when I using which vim to find the path of vim, it give the /usr/bin/vim which should be the **vim 7.2**, I expect it should be /home/zijwu/tools/bin/vim (~/tools/bin/vim)

Following is the command and output from the terminal, So why the which give incorrect path?

```
>vim --version

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jul 11 2013 12:17:16)

>/usr/bin/vim --version

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Nov 15 2012 00:32:35)

>~/tools/bin/vim --version

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jul 11 2013 12:17:16)

>echo $PATH

~/tools/bin:~/mercurial-2.6.3:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

>which vim

/usr/bin/vim
```

Comment: What does "which which" give?

Comment: It give following result "/usr/bin/which"

Comment: `strace /usr/bin/which vim` -- might be interesting to see if it encountered some kind of challenge when looking at the `vim` binary located in `~/tools/bin`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting your `$PATH` incorrectly. In looking at `$PATH` entries, no tilde expansion is done, so `~/tools/bin` would actually search (effectively) `./~/tools/bin`, not `$HOME/tools/bin`.